# How do I publish to someone's news stream programmatically in FaceBook?

Tags: c#, vb.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have the publish_stream extended permission for a Facebook app, how do I publish to a user's news stream without prompting them with the dialog? I have the permission so I should be able to do it programatically, yes?

I am using the Facebook C# SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but strongly advised against by facebook.  You should always ask for permission PER POST to the user's wall.

You need to POST to https://graph.facebook.com/[UID HERE]/feed

with these parameters:

```
    {"name": "Link name"
     "link": "http://www.example.com/",
     "caption": "{*actor*} posted a new review",
     "description": "This is a longer description of the attachment",
     "picture": "http://www.example.com/thumbnail.jpg"}
```